Did the examiner force the inventor to narrow the scope of the central concept of this patent?
original patent:
https://patents.google.com/patent/US11386172B1/en?oq=11%2c386%2c172
https://patentcenter.uspto.gov/applications/15916086/ifw/docs?application=
continued patent:
https://patents.google.com/patent/US12019694B1/en?oq=11%2c386%2c172
https://patentcenter.uspto.gov/applications/17861962/ifw/docs?application=

These patents relate to online dating applications and matching users.
The central concept of the invention described in the spec is the "commitment disposition" or "intention".
In the spec, this concept is only ever described as a numeric range or scale of some sort.
Going through the patent center transaction records, it appears that the applicant tried to remove the limitation of it being a numeric range in the claims in both applications.
In the initial claims submitted, before examination, there is no use of the term "level" in the original application and there is no use of the term "range" in the continued application.
The examiner did find prior art that uses relationship intentions, such as "casual dating", "short-term dating", etc. But I believe that the prior art did not describe these intentions as numeric ranges with inherent order.
And so, in the granted claims of the original patent, the term "level" was added to the claims. This term was not present in the initial claims, before examination. Without the term "level", I believe that the examiner interpreted the claims to include possibilities of it being more than a numeric range.
And in the granted claims of the continued patent, the term "range" was added to the claims. In the initial claims, before examination, the language was selecting an intention from "multiple" available intentions. It also appeared that in a later response, it tried with a "collection" of intentions. Both the terms "multiple" and "collection" do not imply limiting to a numeric range, hence I believe that the examiner forced the applicant to finally settle for the term "range".
Questions:

Going through the transactions of the prosecution of both patents, do you believe the original attempt of the applicant was to remove the limitation of the "commitment disposition" and "intention" being limited to a numeric range?
Did the patent examiner ultimately force the claims to be limited to a numeric range in both of the granted patents?


Haven't dug into the documents but I would be surprised if non-numeric measures of intent were supported by the specification in question. Computers deal with numbers.

@bhuff36 No, I meant that the intent has to interpreted as a range of ordered values even from the perspective of the human. For example, intent implemented as discrete categories like "dating", "marriage", etc. WITHOUT order is in pretty much all dating apps. But if you turn intent into an ordered range of values, you could have a new way of matching values that are not EXACTLY equal because numbers that are closer together are more similar.

_Bear: numeric values are a special case of having a cost matrix that can define the difference between any pair of discrete categories. If the specification didn't mention a cost matrix that might be one reason to limit to numeric values.

@bhuff36 No, by discrete value, I just meant that they were simple strings or character values without any intrinsic order or relationship. So for example, "casual dating" , "dating", and "serious dating" are just merely strings. However, if you map these values to a numeric range or scale, such as 1 for "casual dating", 2 for "dating", and 3 for "serious dating", then you have defined some relation between these values. So this might be where the novelty lies.
